# Using inline assembly in c to check for the largest value in a 32-bit integer array

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm attempting to find the maximum element in an integer array using inline assembly in c. Below is my attempted solution with comments attached showing my logic.

**My attempt:**

```c
static inline int max_elem()
{
  int list[] = {1,8,6,2,3};
  int max, temp;
  int length = 5;

 asm volatile(
  /* initialize max */
  "init:    mov (%1), %0;"
  "         jmp start;

  /* increment arr to point to next int in memory (4-bytes) */
  "start:   add $4, %1;"

  /* check if you looped through all elements */       
  "         sub $1, %3;"
  "         cmp $0, %3;"
  "         je done;"

  /* compare max with current element in list */
  "         mov (%1), %2;"
  "         cmp %2, %0;"
  "         jl new_max;"

  "new_max: mov %2, %0;"
  "         jmp start;"

  "done: ;"
  : "=a" (max) /* assign max to traditional return register */
  : "r" (list), "r" (temp), "r" (length) /* compiler picks the assignment of input variables */
 );
}
```

My attempted solution seems to give me a segmentation fault, despite my logic seeming correct to me. Any additional help or input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which processor, compiler, and hosting environment?

Comment: It is a bad idea to use inline asm for this. Are you forced to do it this way (e.g. as part of an assignment?) Anyway, examine the generated assembly and use a debugger. From a quick glance, your problem might be that you forgot to specify the output as early-clobber. The compiler may allocate outputs overlapping with inputs unless told otherwise. PS: your code is broken though, `jl new_max` should probably be `jge start`. As it is, you are falling through into `new_max` either way.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, everything is working now. The main issue was me not specifying the early-clobber register. Should I just be declaring a output register to be an early-clobber when the output register will be used before all of the input registers are used?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the use case.

Comment: Another point is that you had better use [local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Symbol-Names.html).  As it stands, when your function is inlined, your assembly snippet may appear many times in the compiler's output, and the assembler will complain about the multiply defined labels.  This will also avoid a conflict if you should someday define a function or global variable called `done`, `new_max`, etc.

Comment: Another issue is that you are modifying your input operands %1 and %2 without telling the compiler. If you’re trying to learn assembly, I strongly recommend that you create an assembly file instead of using inline assembly.

Comment: You need to add `return max` after the assembly code so the compiler can see what max_elem is returning. Just putting it in eax is insufficient, especially when the function is being inlined.

Comment: `temp` needs to be a dummy *output* because you write it.  (Instead of reading the uninitialized value as an input).  Also, you need a `"memory"` clobber because you take a pointer to `list` as an input, not the actual memory contents of the array itself.  If you're going to use pointers / your own addressing modes in inline asm, you always need a memory clobber, or fully understand [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259).  Same problem I commented about in your `lodsb` question.